# Java Swing Scroll Bars on table I've looked at a lot of different guides doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I've been writing a constructor. To create a table. However I want it to have scroll bars on the table. I've been doing a lot of searching on how to do it correctly. However it doesn't seem to be working. I am unsure as to where I am going wrong.

```
public ApplicationPanel(String[][] data, String[] colNames)
{   
   JTable table = new JTable(data, colNames);

   table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450, 65));
   table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
   TableColumn column;

   JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

   scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,800));

 //  column.setResizable(true);
   for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
   {
       column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
       if (i == 2)
       {
           column.setPreferredWidth(400);     
       }
       else
       {
           column.setPreferredWidth(50);
       }
   }
   this.add(scrollPane);
}
```

Comment: Clarify what's going wrong with your `ScrollBar`'s.

Comment: Try the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show).

Comment: @alex2410 What going on is that it is not in the program. As in yes coding wise it looks like I'm creating it but it's not there.

Comment: Try to add `table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);` and resize parent `JFrame`, you'll see them.

Comment: @alex2410 I just get this really random blank space [image link](http://imgur.com/k4Zlbjk)

Comment: If you need to fill all area with `JTable` and see `JScrollBar`s always try to create use `JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);`

Answer (score 0):

Filled the area as @alex2410 suggested with the following code added to the constructor.

```
 this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

After which table scroll bars are now viewable. **Combine this with the code above** (minus the code below and you should have a working table constructor with scroll bars.

The following code was **removed** and at some point was in the code. So for reference these do not appear to have any effect of which I can tell.

```
   table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450, 65));
   table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
   table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
   scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_S‌​CROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
   ApplicationFrame.getFrames().getContentPane().add( new JScrollPane( table ), BorderLayout.CENTER );
   column.setResizable(true);
```